# Inline return to original caller

Tags: c++, return, inline

I have a C++ wrapper to wrap a library for C. The wrapper frequently performs a variable check. I would like to break this down into an inline function call, but I would like the inline function to return to the original caller if the check fails.

For the sake of simplicity, we'll call the library I wrapped `libraryA` and we'll call the library's object `objectA`.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
#define LIBRARY_A_NULL_PARAMETER    -1
#define LIBRARY_A_CAST_FAIL         -2
signed int wrapper_doSomething(void *ptrVariable){
    libraryA::objectA *objA;
    /* variable checks */
    if(!ptrVariable){
        return LIBRARY_A_NULL_PARAMETER;
    }
    try{
        objA = (libraryA::objectA *)ptrVariable;
    }catch(...){
        return LIBRARY_A_CAST_FAIL;
    }
    /* perform the rest of the function */
}
```

Because this check is performed in nearly every function, I'd like to simplify this to something like:

```
#define LIBRARY_A_NULL_PARAMETER    -1
#define LIBRARY_A_CAST_FAIL         -2

inline signed int checkVariable(void *ptrVariable, libraryA::objectA **assignTo){
    if(!ptrVariable){
        return LIBRARY_A_NULL_PARAMETER;
    }
    try{
        *assignTo = (libraryA::objectA *)ptrVariable;
        return 1; // success
    }catch(...){
        return LIBRARY_A_CAST_FAIL;
    }
}

signed int wrapper_doSomething(void *ptrVariable){
    libraryA::objectA *objA;
    /* variable checks */

    checkVariable(ptrVariable, &objA);

    /* perform the rest of the function */
}
```

I'd like the `checkVariable()` function to return back to the original caller if the check fails.

Because all error codes are negative numbers, I can of course say:

```
int response = checkVariable(ptrVariable, &objA);
if(response < 0){
    return response;
}
```

This would handle the situation, but I would like to remove the `if-statement`, if possible, and thus reduce the variable check to exactly one line. Is this achievable?

I plan on looking into macros, but I have not used macros before, so I'm not sure if they could accomplish this either.

---

**EDIT:**

Per Anton's answer, would a macro definition like this suffice:

```
#define CHECK_VARIABLE(ptrVariable, objA) \
{\
    if(!ptrVariable) return LIBRARY_A_NULL_PARAMETER;\
    try{\
        *objA = (libraryA::objectA *)ptrVariable;\
    }catch(...){\
        return LIBRARY_A_CAST_FAIL;\
    }\
}
```

I would then call it as:

```
CHECK_VARIABLE(ptrVariable, &objA);
```

Comment: note that `objA` inside the last piece of code with if(response...) will not be updated

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'll correct that momentarily.

Comment: Does it really need to be an inline function? I fear that a function which catches exceptions would be too complex to be inlined anyway.

Comment: I'd prefer to make inline to reduce function-call overhead. It will increase the filesize, but currently it's all written in the functions themselves, so `inline` shouldn't produce a noticeable binary size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without exceptions you have to use macros. Given you have `checkVariable()` function, the macro can look like this:

```
#define CHECK_VARIABLE(ptrVariable, objA) \
    {\
        int response = checkVariable((ptrVariable), &(objA));\
        if (response < 0)\
            return response;\
    }
```

Comment: hmm alright. Could I use `try-catch` statements in the macro? If so, could I rewrite `checkVariable` inside of the macro definition? If you're willing to entertain it, I'll update my question really quickly to show the macro I have in mind.

Comment: Yes you can put the whole body of `checkVariable()` inside a macro, but I wouldn't advise to do that. You gain nothing but you lose the ability to debug it and to use it differently than from a macro.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using exceptions already, you can use them for that purpose, too:

```
inline signed int checkVariable(void *ptrVariable, libraryA::objectA **assignTo) {
    if (!ptrVariable) {
        throw LIBRARY_A_NULL_PARAMETER;
    }
    try {
        *assignTo = (libraryA::objectA *)ptrVariable;
        return 1; // success
    } catch(...) {
        throw LIBRARY_A_CAST_FAIL;
    }
}
```

You can write the `wrapper_doSomething` function exactly as desired but the caller of that function has to catch the exception that is passed along.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll update my question. The wrapper is for C. I'm using C++ to wrap a C++ library and use it in C. C does not have a try-catch handler. Thank you for the answer nonetheless.